# Аббревиатуры на звонкое согласное тоже оглушаются?

Tags: фонетика

К примеру, МИД, как произносится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оглушаются, разумеется. Это фонетический закон языка, он не может действовать выборочно. 
Да вы просто попробуйте произнести не оглушая - без некоторой тренировки и не получится.

Чтобы понять место подобных фонетических законов, сопоставьте с тем, как сложно бывает изучающему английский, например, язык избавиться от привычки оглушать согласные. Какие уж тут аббревиатуры, когда закон даже на иностранный язык подсознательно переносится.

Единственное, что могу добавить. Аббревиатуру (не МИД, более сложную) по объективным причинам чаще приходится произносить по буквам для лучшего понимания, там иногда приходится упражняться в "неоглушенном" произношении.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется Д произносится звонким. Мне кажется, иначе и при желании не скажешь. Вспомните, как говорят дикторы по телевидению (там это слово можно услышать чаще всего) — они всегда произносят четко со звонком Д на конце.
Мне кажется, что в аббревиатурах как раз нужно произносить согласные четче, чем в полных словах.

Comment: Никогда не слышал, чтобы дикторы так ломали язык. Наоборот, их контролируют на предмет соблюдения общих орфоэпических норм.
Думаю, это наш мозг домысливает за диктора.

Comment: Не  скажу  за  все  аббревиатуры,  но  в  МИД  звонкость  ощущается  явно.  Сложнее  произнести  МИТ и  представить  Министерство  иностранных  дел.

Answer (score 0):

Это мои собственные наблюдения и на достоверность не претендую.
Звонкие звуки короче звуков глухих. При оглушении согласного время его произнесения как правило совпадает с временем произнесения звука изначального, причём зачастую это время сохраняется даже, если звук оглушается аж до полного непроизнесения.
В данном случае звук на конце "МИД" будет оглушен как "т", но долгота произношения будет как у звука "д".

Comment: По  моему  глухие  короче  звонких. Дальнейшее  не  очень  понятно. Может  примеров  привести  побольше.

Comment: Примеры дать без аудио проблематично, но попробую. Звук на конце слова "маг" больше похож на звук на конце шотландской приставки "mac", чем на то, что мы слышим в конце названия цветка "мак".
Звонкий звук при оглушении, по моим ощущениям, произносится короче, чем глухой.

Comment: Глухие и звонкие по долготе не различаются.
Вообще о "длине" имеет смысл говорить только в отношении свистящих и сонорных. Взрывные аффрикаты и смычные (Т/Д, Б/П, В/Ф, К/Г, Ч) "длины" как таковой не имеют, звук образуется при резком открытии "замка".

Comment: Всё  правильно - не  различаются.  Но мы  с  Владиславом  говорим  о  том,  как  нам  слышится,  причём,  то,  что  слышим  оцениваем  наоборот.  Может  здесь  имеет  место  зрительная  память,  и  мозг  корректирует.